# Is there a mathematical object called "ivy"?

Tags: definitions, terminology

As the title says, is there a mathematical object referred to as "ivy" or "ivy type" or similar?

I have a type of graph where this name fits perfectly, but I don't want it to clash with something already defined.

(I could in this paper call it a "reduced graph" or "contracted graph" but the above definition would make more sense.)

Comment: If it fits perfectly for you, then use it anyway, even if it already has imperfect meaning elsewhere.

Comment: "Ivy" might be a problematic name since "an ivy" is very unidiomatic English.

Comment: Yes, it is some sort of plant, but the plants characteristics fits my definition. That is the nice part.

Comment: @Tom: only because ivy is generally used in mass noun constructions.  "An ivy vine" is perfectly idiomatic English; "an ivy graph" would be fine in maths.

Comment: I trust that these graphs aren't poisonous.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ivy does not appear to be a common term in mathscinet.  Integrable vector Young functions are called IVY-functions in [MR2055989](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2055989) and related papers.  Otherwise all occurrences are the plant or a person.

Comment: Thanks, what I write is related to complex analysis and graph theory, so this won't be closely related notions.